# Getting variables and methods of class from loaded class.

Tags: java, variables, classloader, urlclassloader

My scenario:

A class is going to be loaded from a number of different classes using ClassLoader.

How do I get the methods and variables from the class that loads another class - from the other class? I.e. getting methods and variables from a class I do not know the name of.

Example:

```
public class MainClass {
 public static String str = "hey";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //load the OtherClass class, create an instance of it, and invoke its run method
 }
}

public class OtherClass {
 public void run() {
  //get all variables of the class that instantialized the class
 }
}
```

Searched stackoverflow but with no luck :/

Any help appreciated :).

Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
public class OtherClass {
  public void run(Object invokerObject) {
     Class invoker = invokerObject.getClass();
     Field[] fields = invoker.getFields();
     for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
       // retrieve info from fields[i]      .
     }
     Method[] methods = invoker.getMethods();
     for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
       // retrieve info from methods[i]     .
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks :).

Also: is it possible to get the local variables (i.e. the variables only declared and used in methods) of the methods of the invoking class?

Comment: Local variable are not field of a class, they are only temporary, so i presume it is not possible. Anyway, what do you want to do with this code?
+1 ;)

Comment: If you mean the variable declared and visible in all the body of the class (also private ones),but not in the methods, then you can use getDeclaredFields().

Comment: I don't think you can get the actual stack frame data. Even a `Method` object only references the class member, not particular specific instance of the method as it is being executed. To get at what I think you want, you'll have to use the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your asking, but it sounds like you want the dynamically loaded class to have access to the fields and methods of the class containing the code from wich `run()` was called. You can do this:

```
// you might need [2] in the following line
String callerClass = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
```

This is the fully-qualified class name from which the current method was called. Once you have that, you can access the fields and methods of that class using reflection:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(callerClass);
Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
```

If you want the non-accessible members as well, use `getDeclaredFields()` and `getDeclaredMethods()`.

For other ideas, take a look at [this post](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/05/finding-caller-of-instance-or-static.html).

Comment: This is what I'm looking for :)..

Is it possible to get local variables from the methods of the class that called run() ? (Including the values of the variables)

Comment: [1] seems to return the class of the current thread (i.e. the OtherClass). [2] throws a ClassNotFoundException

Comment: I don't think any Java-only method is entirely reliable. With many VMs, `getStackTrace()` returns something that's been doctored (sometimes heavily).

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished via [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).